# Failed to find match for field 'intensity' with Ouster LIDAR

Tags: ros, lidar, pcl-conversions, sensor-msgs, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I tried to convert Ouster lidar packets to `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>` using the standard `pcl::fromROSMsg`. I have the error complaining about the conversion can't find the field intensity.
However, carefully inspect the `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` message, I see that it has the intensity field

```
rostopic echo /os1_node/points 
  header: 
  seq: 2
  stamp: 
    secs: 1528426469
    nsecs: 194866238
  frame_id: "os1"
height: 1
width: 65536
fields: 
  - 
    name: "x"
    offset: 0
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "y"
    offset: 4
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "z"
    offset: 8
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "t"
    offset: 16
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "reflectivity"
    offset: 20
    datatype: 4
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "intensity"
    offset: 22
    datatype: 4
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "ring"
    offset: 24
    datatype: 2
    count: 1
is_bigendian: False
point_step: 32
row_step: 2097152
```

And I can print the intensity value of a point

```
pcl::fromROSMsg(*laserCloudMsg, *laserCloudIn);
 ROS_INFO("Point intensity %f ",laserCloudIn->points[3].intensity);
Failed to find match for field 'intensity'.
[ INFO] [1541667829.480241159, 1528426469.011953052]: Point intensity 0.994560 
Failed to find match for field 'intensity'.
[ INFO] [1541667838.574432769, 1528426469.102849368]: Point intensity 0.025828
```

Here I do not understand why I still get the error `Failed to find match for field intensity`.

I greatly appreciate your help!

EDIT1: @PeteBlackerThe3rd, thank for your help.
According to the User manual,

> Lidar data packets consist of 16
> azimuth blocks and are always 12608
> Bytes in length. The packet rate is
> dependent on the output mode. ​Words
> are 32 bits in length.

Each azimuth block contains:

● Timestamp ​[64 bits] - Unique time in nanoseconds.

● Measurement ID ​ [32 bits] - a sequentially incrementing azimuth measurement counting
up from 0 to 511, or 0 to 1023, or 0 to 2047 depending on lidar_mode.

● Encoder Count ​ [32 bits] - an azimuth angle as a raw encoder count, starting from 0 with
a max value of 90111 - incrementing 44 ticks every azimuth angle in x2048 mode, 88
ticks in x1024 mode, and 176 ticks in x512 mode.

● Data Block ​ [96 bits] - 3 data words for each of the 16 or 64 pixels. See ​Table below for
full definition.
○ Range ​[20 bits] - Range in millimeters, discretized to the nearest 12 millimeters.
○ Reflectivity ​[16 bits] - Sensor signal_photon measurements are scaled based on
measured range and sensor sensitivity at that range, providing an indication of
target reflectivity. Calibration of this measurement has not currently been
rigorously implemented, but this will be updated in future a future firmware
release.
○ Signal Photons ​[16 bits] - Signal photons in the signal return measurement are
reported
○ Noise Photons ​[16 bits] - Noise photons in the noise return measurement are
reported.

● Packet Status ​ - indicates whether the azimuth block is good or bad. Good =
0xFFFFFFFF, Bad = 0x0. If a packet is bad ​Measurement ID ​, ​Encoder Count ​, and ​Data
Bock:Range ​ and ​Data Block:Reflectivity ​ will also be set to 0x0.

The driver indeed does provide pointcloud messages directly. The conversion is for my segmentation algorithm. I can't understand why `pcl::fromROSMsg` complains that there is no intensity field to match while I can output intensity value for each point.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307881/failed-to-find-match-for-field-%27intensity%27-with-ouster-lidar/) by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 358 on 2018-11-08

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-11-08**:
What message format are the Ouster lidar packets in? I've found most 3D LiDAR drivers produce PointCloud messages directly, which don't need conversion to pcl. At times though I've found that conversions have failed due to case sensitivity.

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-11-08**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd please see my EDIT1. I use the official driver provided by the company. It's true that in some case the `intensity` field is named as `intensities` but not with this lidar.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-11-08**:
My guess would be that the ros converter is expecting the fields x, y, z & intensity. The additional fields may be confusing it. I have some cpp code which I'll post in a few minutes which enables you to manually extract fields into a pcl::PointCloud object. I'll just dig it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here are a few things that hopefully will help you get this working properly.

The point cloud message you posted the rostopic echo of has a custom point type with values (x,y,z,t,reflectivity,intensity,ring) to be able to use this type of point cloud with the C++ PCL library there will need to be a definition of this non-standard point type. This should look something like this code snippet from some of my work with ROS LiDAR hardware drivers:

```
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

/// Custom PCL point type with additional point data 
struct OcularPointType
{
  PCL_ADD_POINT4D;
  float amplitude;
  float reflectance;
  int pulseShapeDeviation;
  unsigned int timestamp;
  EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
} EIGEN_ALIGN16;

POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (CustomPointType,
                                   (float, x, x)
                                   (float, y, y)
                                   (float, z, z)
                                   (float, amplitude, amplitude)
                                   (float, reflectance, reflectance)
                                   (float, pulseShapeDeviation, pulseShapeDeviation)
                                   (unsigned int, timestamp, timestamp)
)
```

This then allows you to use it with all the standard PCL functions. The ROS driver for your LiDAR should include a definition of this in a in include file somewhere, in which case you will be able to work with these point clouds natively.

If this doesn't get it working here is a last resort solution. The following template function demonstrates how to parse the ROS PointCloud2 message into a pcl::PointCloud yourself, this is doing the job of pcl::fromROSMsg but you can see exactly what's going on and fix it if you need to.

```
void yourPointCloud2Callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 & cloud_msg)
{
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> cloud;

  // Get the field structure of this point cloud
  int pointBytes = cloud_msg.point_step;
  int offset_x;
  int offset_y;
  int offset_z;
  int offset_int;
  for (int f=0; f<cloud_msg.fields.size(); ++f)
  {
    if (cloud_msg.fields[f].name == "x")
      offset_x = cloud_msg.fields[f].offset;
    if (cloud_msg.fields[f].name == "y")
      offset_y = cloud_msg.fields[f].offset;
    if (cloud_msg.fields[f].name == "z")
      offset_z = cloud_msg.fields[f].offset;
    if (cloud_msg.fields[f].name == "intensity")
      offset_int = cloud_msg.fields[f].offset;
  }

  // populate point cloud object
  for (int p=0; p<cloud_msg.width; ++p)
  {
      pcl::PointXYZI newPoint;

      newPoint.x = *(float*)(&cloud_msg.data[0] + (pointBytes*p) + offset_x);
      newPoint.y = *(float*)(&cloud_msg.data[0] + (pointBytes*p) + offset_y);
      newPoint.z = *(float*)(&cloud_msg.data[0] + (pointBytes*p) + offset_z);
      newPoint.intensity = *(unsigned char*)(&cloud_msg.data[0] + (pointBytes*p) + offset_int);

      cloud.points.push_back(newPoint);
  }

// The rest of your function here....

}
```

Hope this helps you get this working.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-11-08**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd I greatly appreciate your help. Indeed, the struct to define the point is provided by the driver, that's why I can get `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` messages from `ouster_lidar_packets`. I will use your method to manually populate the pointcloud object and see if it correctly...

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-11-08**:
parses the intensity. Thanks again! I will get back asap.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-11-08**:
Okay, note my code example is for a 8 bit unsigned intensity whereas your Lidar message have 16 bit unsigned intensity values (type #4)

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-11-09**:
Did you have any luck getting this working?

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-11-09**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd , thanks for your help. I change `unsigned char` to `uint16_t` to fit my data. Though we should find a way to avoid C-style casting :)

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-11-09**:
I agree it's rather low level. I may have a look at the source of fromROSMsg when I get a chance and find out why it isn't working in your case.

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-11-09**:
I did try that too but no success :(. I think the problem is [here #L169](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/conversions_8h_source.html) where the function makes `memcpy` of the data field. I suspect something is wrong when it try to read the data type of my lidar intensity.

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-11-09**:
And using for loop is definitely slower. I try your function with the normal Velodyne data and the conversion time is 2-3 times slower than using `pcl::fromROSMsg`.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-11-09**:
I'm sure it is. My code was only ever intended to debug a similar problem we had once. Using std::vector::push_back is probably the biggest performance hit. Pre-allocating the array would probably speed it up noticeably.